# Test events fired by third-party component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library, testing-library

I wrote a component that uses `Player` from `@vimeo/player` but now I am unsure how to write tests that are not focused on implementation details. I am using `testing-library`.
Specifically, I am looking for a way to test state changes that stem from these events (`loaded`, `bufferstart`, `bufferend`, `play`, `pause`):

```
    useEffect(() => {
        async function setupPlayer() {
            if (playerRef.current) {
                playerRef.current.on('loaded', () => setIsLoading(false));
                playerRef.current.on('bufferstart', () => setIsBuffering(true));
                playerRef.current.on('bufferend', () => setIsBuffering(false));
                playerRef.current.on('play', () => setIsPlaying(true));
                playerRef.current.on('pause', () => setIsPlaying(false));
            }
        }

        if (playerRef.current) {
            playerRef.current = new Player(
                playerRef.current,
                { url: `https://player.vimeo.com/video/${video}`,
                    loop: true,
                    title: false,
                    portrait: false,
                    controls: false,
                    byline: false,
                    muted: true,
                    responsive: true },
            );
            setupPlayer();
        }

        return () => playerRef.current && playerRef.current.destroy();
    }, [playerRef]);
```

My goal is to test for example that a loading/buffering has been rendered until `loaded`/`bufferend` events are fired.

```
  /* eslint-disable max-len */
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import Button from 'button';
import { IconScan, IconPause, IconPlay } from 'iconography';
import Loader from 'loader';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import Player from '@vimeo/player';

const VIDEO_PLAYER_INDEX = 2;

const VideoPlayer = ({ wrapperEl,
    video,
    style,
    wrapperClassNames,
    renderedInOverlay,
    onSetOverlay,
    isMobile }) => {
    const playerRef = useRef();
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
    const [isHovering, setIsHovering] = useState(true);
    const [isBuffering, setIsBuffering] = useState(false);
    const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);
    const [height, setHeight] =  useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function setupPlayer() {
            if (playerRef.current) {
                playerRef.current.on('loaded', (e) => {
                    setIsLoading(false);
                    console.log(e);
                });
                playerRef.current.on('bufferstart', () => setIsBuffering(true));
                playerRef.current.on('bufferend', () => setIsBuffering(false));
                playerRef.current.on('play', () => setIsPlaying(true));
                playerRef.current.on('pause', () => setIsPlaying(false));
            }
        }

        if (playerRef.current) {
            playerRef.current = new Player(
                playerRef.current,
                { url: `https://player.vimeo.com/video/${video}`,
                    loop: true,
                    title: false,
                    portrait: false,
                    controls: false,
                    byline: false,
                    muted: true,
                    responsive: true },
            );
            setupPlayer();
        }

        return () => playerRef.current && playerRef.current.destroy();
    }, [playerRef]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isMobile && isPlaying && !isBuffering) {
            setIsHovering(false);
        }
    }, [isPlaying, isMobile, isBuffering]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (playerRef.current) {
            Promise.all([playerRef.current.getVideoWidth(), playerRef.current.getVideoHeight()]).then((dimensions) => {
                setWidth(dimensions[0]);
                setHeight(dimensions[1]);
            });
        }
    }, [isMobile, playerRef]);

    const handlePlayClick = () => {
        if (isPlaying) {
            playerRef.current.pause();
        } else if (!isPlaying && !isBuffering) {
            playerRef.current.play();
        }
    };

    const renderIframe =  () => {
        if (!video) return null;

        const showControls = isHovering || !isPlaying || isBuffering;
        const showPlay = isPlaying && !isBuffering;
        const aspectRatio = (width / height) * 100;
        const wrapperBtnStyle = renderedInOverlay ? { style: { maxWidth: `${aspectRatio}vh` } } : {};

        return (
            <div className={ classNames('video-player', { 'video-player--is-loading': isLoading }) }>
                <Button
                    className="video-player__wrapper-btn"
                    variant="naked"
                    onClick={ () => handlePlayClick() }
                    onMouseEnter={ () => setIsHovering(true) }
                    onMouseLeave={ () => setIsHovering(false) }
                    { ...wrapperBtnStyle }>
                    <div
                        ref={ playerRef }
                        className="video-player__player"
                        data-testid="video-player"
                    />
                    { showControls &&
                        <div className="video-player__controls-container">
                            <div className="video-player__controls-btn" >
                                {showPlay ?
                                    <IconPause size="lg" title="Pause" className="video-player__control-icon" />
                                    :
                                    <IconPlay size="lg" title="Play" className="video-player__control-icon" />
                                }
                            </div>
                            {isBuffering && (
                                <div className="video-player__buffer-container">
                                    <div className="video-player__buffer-indicator" />
                                </div>)}
                        </div>
                    }
                </Button>
                { !renderedInOverlay &&
                    <div className="video-player__fullscreen-btn-container">
                        <Button
                            className="video-player__fullscreen-btn"
                            variant="naked"
                            onClick={ (e) => onSetOverlay(e, false, VIDEO_PLAYER_INDEX) }
                            onTouchStart={ (e) => onSetOverlay(e, false, VIDEO_PLAYER_INDEX) }>
                            <IconScan size="lg" title="Fullscreen" />
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                }
                <Loader className="video-player__loader" height={ 30 } />
            </div>
        );
    };

    return (
        wrapperEl ?
            React.createElement(
                wrapperEl,
                {
                    className: classNames(wrapperClassNames),
                    style,
                },
                renderIframe(),
            )
            : renderIframe()
    );
};

VideoPlayer.defaultProps = {
    video: '',
    wrapperEl: '',
    wrapperClassNames: '',
    style: {},
    renderedInOverlay: false,
    isMobile: false,
};

VideoPlayer.propTypes = {
    video: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    wrapperEl: PropTypes.string,
    wrapperClassNames: PropTypes.string,
    style: PropTypes.shape({}),
    renderedInOverlay: PropTypes.bool,
    isMobile: PropTypes.bool,
};

export {
    VideoPlayer,
    VIDEO_PLAYER_INDEX,
};
```

Is someone able to give me a pointer how I can achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, complete code example? Where do `playerRef`, `isBuffering` come from?

Comment: Sorry, added the entire component